# Does SignalR 1.1.3 work reliably with IIS6

Tags: c#, javascript, web, signalr

Hi We Have a web application that uses SignalR 1.1.3 and has always worked fine in IIS7 and above.  However since being deployed to an IIS6 server the communication between the client and server is erratic - sometimes a message will be successfully transmitted and received and sometime not

Is there additional configuration required to 'help' the SignalR communicate reliably

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started/supported-platforms

It even states the following:

> Message delays of up to 30 seconds may be experienced if IIS is run in classic mode using the Server-Sent Events transport.

Trying to make it work seems like a lost cause then. But, here's a shot in the dark: try increasing the maximum number of connections, who knows...

Comment: Cheers for the response